# View / install certificates for local machine store on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

On Windows 7 (Windows 7 Professional x64), how can I view and install certificates in the local machine store?

The *certmgr.msc* plugin allows me to view certificates installed in the current user store, but not the local machine store.

I am attempting to install from a .PFX file. On Windows 8, you are presented with an option to install either to local machine or current user store, but this option does not appear to be present in Windows 7.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Start mmc.exe (as administrator), menu *File* -> *Add/Remove Snap-in..*,  select "Certificates", press <kbd>Add</kbd>, select radio button "Computer account", press <kbd>Finish</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: This is great.  Is there a way to do this at the command line, rather than drag-and-drop ?  Seems to me the command line was only dealing with my currentUser store.

Comment: CertMgr.exe is the way to do it on cmdline...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you just want to access your own certificates (not the machine certificates), then you don't need to be an administrator to follow these directions.

Comment: "If you just want to access your own certificates (not the machine certificates)" - those answers seem to be always strange. Topic starter clearly wrote above "FOR LOCAL MACHINE"

Comment: Where is this radio button "Computer account" in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 21):

certlm.msc (Win8/2012 and above) will open the local machine's certificate store in the same GUI style as certmgr.msc.

Comment: I got the error message *"certlm.msc. Windows cannot find 'certlm.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."* on Windows 7 Enterprise when I tried it.

Comment: certificates.msc appears to work in Windows 7 to display the local computer certificates.

Answer (score 8):

Install the certificate for all users:

1. First save the certificate in a file
2. Run MMC
3. Open the Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc in C:\Windows\System32)
4. You will see it opens 'Certificates - Current User'
5. In the menu, choose File, Add/Remove Snap-In

   - Now press Add, select 'Certificates' and select 'Computer Account'
   - Select the Local Computer
   - Now you have two snap-ins:

     - Certificates - Current User
     - Certificates (Local Computer)
6. Now import the certificate in "Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certificates\Certificates""Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certificates\Certificates"

http://www.arcencus.nl/Blogs/tabid/105/EntryID/39/Default.aspx

- Performing this task using the Certificate Manager on the local machine.

  - Launch mmc.exe, if a User Account Control prompt is displayed, click Yes.
- Add the Certificate Management snap-in. Click File, Add/Remove Snap-in…, Certificates. Click Add, click Computer account, Next.
- Retain “Local computer” selection,

  - => Finish, OK.