# How can I sign an MS Word macro with a digital certificate from the local machine certificate store?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, certificate, digital-signature

I am trying to find out how I can digitally sign a Microsoft Word macro using a valid 3rd party CA issued VBA code-signing certificate that is installed into the **machine** rather than the **user** certificate store.

This signing certificate will be used by many different people. I would like anyone who has access to the machine to be able to use it.

I am using the Digital Signature option in the VBA editor (*Alt+F11 > Tools > Digital Signature*) to perform the signing process. Unless the certificate is installed into the user certificate store there are no '*Sign as*' certificates are available, '*Choose...*' shows a warning that '*No certificate available*'.

If I move the certificate from the **Local Computer > Personal** store to the **Current User > Personal** store then it becomes available for selection.

Can the local machine store be used with MS Word VBA code-signing? I believe that this configuration is possible when signing installers using Visual Studio.

Comment: VBA has a severely curtailed feature set relative to Visual Studio. If there are no obvious options in the *Digital Signature* dialog for signing with local machine certificates, then it's very likely not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View / install certificates for local machine store on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/647036/view-install-certificates-for-local-machine-store-on-windows-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying data from multiple word docs into one excel sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/645165/copying-data-from-multiple-word-docs-into-one-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

See https://serverfault.com/questions/1078351/how-do-i-fix-no-usable-signing-certificates-are-available-in-vba, but that basically boils down to you need to put the certificate in the personal certificate store instead of the local machine store.  Mostly because, as @hBy2Py said, "VBA has a severely curtailed feature set".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1148851)

Comment: @DarkDiamond I did "include the essential parts of the answer", which started at "that basically boils down to...".  Not really sure what more you would want.